# Why is subscribersGained - subscribersLost different than my current sub count?

Tags: youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I don't see an option in documentation for just "subscribers" but I can take subscribersGained and subtract subscribersLost. However, the number calculated is a bit lower than the actual result. Is there a reason for this or is there a way to actually get raw sub count?

Answer (score 0):

As of writing (June 2021), there is no metric to gather the total number of subscribers via the YouTube Analytics API, although, as you have already noted, it is possible to collect the number of people that have subscribed and unsubscribed. There is currently no [metric](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics) or [dimension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions) that allows this.

A workaround to get the total number of subscribers would be to collect all subscribers and those that have unsubscribed (using the `subscribersGained` and `subscribersLost` metrics), from when a channel was created, and subtracting the one from the other to get the total. eg. -

`Total number of subscribers = subscribersGained - subscribersLost`